# Image with absolute position to position in pdf itext

Tags: image, position, itext, coordinates, scale

So I have an image and I set its position absolute (jsf). Then the user can change the position with the drag/drop functions from primefaces. The new coordinates (left/top) are then stored in the mysql database. When the page is reloaded, the image is again absolutely positioned with the coordinates from the db.
For example the image coordinates are (the page is scrollable): left:68px; top: 826.5px

--> In java I use itext and I want to place the image with the absolute values ​​from the database. I know that the 0/0 coordinates of the PDF document are bottom left.
I want to use image.setAbsolutePosition() but how does the coordinates match???
They right coordinates for the pdf would be: x about 135 and y about 700 but how this fit together with the coordinates on the screen 68px/826.5px? I have already calculate around a lot but do not understand it...

I also scale the images: the original with/height on screen: 35x35
and I use: image.scaleAbsolute(25, 25);

So how does this work? thx :)

Answer (score 4):

If you have an image whose top left corner is at `{x,y}` in a top-left coordinate system and you want to place it in a coordinate system that uses bottom-left for the origin and bottom-left for placement then you need to know both the height of the image and the height of the document. The `{x}` won't change but the new `{y}` should be `Document.Height - {original y} - Image.Height}`.

The image below shows an image that's at `{50,50}` in a top-left system. Once we add it to a document we need to know the document's height (800px) so that we can map. We also need to know the image's height (75px).

[image]

Comment: as I mention the original position of the image is x: 68px y:826.5px because the page is scrollable and the height of the doucment is 842px; so 842 - 826 - 25 = -9 ....

Comment: You'll need a taller document then

Comment: but why I'll need a taller document, the A4page fits! The drag/drop images in my java application are in front of a graphic. This graphic is also at the top of my pdf-document, only a little bit smaller (so also the drag/drop images are smaller). I want that the drag/drop images are at the same postion on this graphic as on the desktop  ... I think there is maybe some conversion of the coordinates necessary (from pixel to units) or sth like that. But I find no way that coordinates match together....

Comment: Your equation above gave you negative nine, that's why I said you'd need a taller document. When converting from top-left to bottom-left systems, the `{x}` never changes (assuming both have `{x}` origins that are the same which is usually zero). If the `{x}` _does_ change or you _want_ it to change then you are no longer doing a straight conversion and you need custom logic. PDFs, unless you change something, use 72 units/inch, and when images are added, 1 unit maps to 1 pixel.

Comment: It should work if I minus the scrollable area from the y-coordinate. The reason why x/y-Coordinates change is because the size of the graphic/area where I dragged/dropped the images is too big for the pdf-document. The orign graphic is 750x389. In the document I scale it to 483x278. So I need to scale all coordinates so that they are fit to the scale graphic...